# Can't import android-async-http in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, gradle, import, settings, loopj

I add `com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9` in ProjectStructure (`AndroidStudio 2.1.2`)
But when graddle script sync i get error

```
Failed to resolve: com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9
```

**app/build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 24
   buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "ru.fvds.suhanov.timetable"
       minSdkVersion 18
       targetSdkVersion 24
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /*testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'*/
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

Help, please

Comment: can you use app compact  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' as this one. let me knw what you get

Comment: I had tried this, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download jar file this link [androidasync jar](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

then right click app directory open module settings